# What are the conditions to apply Brouwer fixed-point theorem (one dimentional case)?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Does this theorem work for a continuous function  $f : ]a,b[ \rightarrow ]a,b[$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{\bar{R}}$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there certain descriptions of $]a,b[$ or is this a typo?

Comment: @Eoin That's a common alternative notation for $(a,b)$.

Comment: Huh, first time I've seen it. @neuguy thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but it does hold for a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to [a,b]$  Here's the proof for the special case when $[a,b]=[0,1]$

Case 1:  $f(0)=0$.  In which case, done, that's our fixed point.  Case 2: $f(1)=1$.  Again, we're done, that's our fixed point.

Case 3:  $f(0)>0,f(1)<1$.   Then define a new function $g(x)=f(x)-x$  on $[0,1]$.  We have $g(0)=f(0)-0>0$,   $g(1)=f(1)-1<0$,  so by the intermediate value theorem,  for some point $c\in (0,1)$,  $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$,  hence $f(c)=c$.

The generalization to $[a,b]$  comes from either redoing the g function or the ultra simple proof that "All continuous functions on the topological space X have a fixed point" is a topological property,  and $[a,b]$  is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the theorem does not hold. For example, define $f:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ to be $f(x) = x^2$. This function has no fixed points on its domain; you need the endpoints for this to work out, which is why you require a compact set.

Answer (score 0):

The set is not compact, so we can't assume that Brouwer's fixed point theorem will hold, as the assumptions are not completely satisfied.

Comment: So, in contrary to the intermediate value theorem we can't generalize the Bouwer fixed-point theorem to $\mathbb{\bar{R}}$ ?

Comment: @Maman The intermediate value theorem is a corrolary of the fact that connected sets are mapped to connected sets by continuous functions. In $\mathbb{R}$ a connected set can be in the form of an open interval or a closed interval. Brouwer's fixed point theorem has the requirement that a set is compact, and convex. The open interval is not a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ by the Heine-Borel Theorem so, it does not generalize to the open set as well.

Comment: Ok and if we define $f: \mathbb{\bar{R}} \rightarrow \mathbb{\bar{R}}$ it can work ?

Comment: @Maman I would think not. A compact set in $\mathbb{R}$ (or as I speculate, similarly in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$) is required to be closed and bounded by the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: For sure but $\mathbb{\bar{R}}$ means that we have $a=-\infty$ and $b=+\infty$ so $\mathbb{\bar{R}}=[-\infty,+\infty]$

Comment: @Maman You then have to decide what topology to use with the two new points,  which is different thant he one point compactification.

Comment: @Alan If I take $f : [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b] : x\rightarrow x^3$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{\bar{R}}$. If $a=-\infty$ then $a^{3}=-\infty$ which is a fixed point. Same thing for $b=+\infty$. However it works only if $f(a)=-\infty$ and $f(b)=+\infty$. Is that right ?

Comment: Honestly not sure

Comment: @Alan you may be right because in the case of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ the function $f(x)-x$ is not defined if $f(x)=+\infty$ and $x=+\infty$...